# Automatic Webpage Data Entry based on The Page Content

Tags: automation, html, data-entry

Is it possible to make a program that open a page (as if a bookmark file were opened by IE), and based on its content generate a feedback, that should be fedback in a textbox on said page by pressing a button on said page?

I need this program to execute on a set time schedule to feed some data to a web server based on time dependent web page data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. It is generally called [screen scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_scraping). You basically retrieve the web page in question via a HTTP request, parse/analyze the page you got, then send back the data that should go into the textbox (again a HTTP request).

There are libraries to do that. Here is an article describing an example in Perl:
http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2003/01/22/mechanize.html